# The entire host gets locked and closes all the applications while bitbake is running

Tags: ubuntu, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have started to see this issue lately where I run `build-image` to compile a Yocto image and it would lock the entire Linux machine after it's done building 60% or so, and upon logging it, you'd see as if the machine was reset.

The dmesg logs look like:

```
  523.735767] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155745.
[  523.735768] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155746.
[  523.735769] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155747.
[  523.735770] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155748.
[  523.735770] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155749.
[  523.735771] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155750.
[  523.735772] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155751.
[  523.735772] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155752.
[  523.735773] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155753.
[  523.735776] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155754.
[  523.735777] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155755.
[  523.735777] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155756.
[  523.735778] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155757.
[  523.735779] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 3155758.
[ 7248.626788] perf: interrupt took too long (2511 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500
[ 8308.051016] show_signal_msg: 19 callbacks suppressed
[ 8308.051018] TeamViewer_Desk[3117]: segfault at 7f3b36502d8e ip 00007f3b47cb0ccb sp 00007f3b26dc4c40 error 4 in libgcc_s.so.1[7f3b47ca2000+16000]
[ 8308.092048] TeamViewer[3014]: segfault at 429745010 ip 00007faf67fc4e38 sp 00007ffd70549770 error 6 in libc-2.23.so[7faf67f43000+1c0000]
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `nice ionice bitbake ...`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like quite a bit of threads were running in parallel causing the system to boot/lock.
Modifying the number of threads to 4 did the trick.

```
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your hardware is ok as those messages suggest the system is struggling with I/O write failures to the disk.